# How often did Ra visit Abydos?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-movie

Do we know how often Ra visited Abydos? Or at least, when was the last time he came to Abydos?
Is there a mention or hint in the movie, during the TV series, in the RPG books or in the novels based on either the movie or the TV series?

The answer does not need to be exact to the minute, an answer saying that he visited every X generations would also suffice.

Comment: Well the **last** time he came to Abydos he got smoked by a nuclear bomb.

Comment: Wish I still had my copy to hand of the first post-movie novel to double check. I know it's addressed there when they are discussing the amount of the fuel which was mined pre- and post- Ra.

Comment: @Broklynite This question is tagged with Stargate SG-1, so I presume that the novels that only follow movie continuity (I recall one that involved Hathor coming to Abydos to get revenge for Ra's death) are probably not what the asker is looking for.

Comment: @Thunderforge I agree that I would prefer the SG-1 continuity, but on the other hand if the movie and its series of novels provide a more exact time period - i.e. less than _a million years_ - then I am all for it.

Comment: @Thunderforge "or in the novels based on either the movie" means SG-1 is not necessary. Yes the one with Hathor was the very end of the first book I believe. I had a bunch of the books but never had them all, and you really didn't want to skip books in that series. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The novelisation of the Stargate: SG1 pilot episode indicates that it's been "*many years*" since Ra visited Abydos. It's worth pointing out that the planet itself is largely worthless other than its captive mining population and it's only when the regular shipments of crystalline ore stop coming through like clockwork that he decides to drop everything and see what's going on.

> *The ship, fully self contained, allowed Ra to fly between the
>   far-flung mining operations he maintained in this corner of the
>   universe.*
>
> *Although **he hadn't been to this small planet for many years,** he had
>   come immediately to find out why the quartz shipment had not been made
>   on time.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Stargate: SG1 - Children of the Gods](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_SG-1_(novel))</sup></sub>

Later we learn that his visits are considered infrequent, even by one of the villages elders but that they're well aware that he's a "***living*** god". This would strongly imply that Ra comes *by every generation or so* to make damn sure the Abydosians know who's in charge.

> *As the third sun surged into the sky marking the official arrival of
>   morning, several thousand of Nagada's citizens had already reached the
>   pyramid, **the feared and seldom seen palace of their living god**.  They
>   gathered into a human sea around the long sloping ramp, the same ramp by
>   which the quartz was delivered to the pyramid.  A steady stream of
>   latecomers continued to feed the crowd's numbers, coming over the dunes
>   in a ragged procession that stretched as far as the eye could see.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Stargate: SG1 - Children of the Gods](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_SG-1_(novel))</sup></sub>